# how to print the array data only in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this return value from the result of my query.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [password] => $2y$10$6D7S2gNkcDciJ7g5z/8sie79iV3FCGhGUCFCPHU3cNNdeUVUbLfQC ) )
```

and this is my query,

```
$sql = "SELECT `$fields` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` {$operator} '$value'";
if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
    if($this->_query->execute()) {
        $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
    } else {
        return $this->_error = true;
    }
}

print_r($this->_result);
```

Now what I want is to display or print only the array data which is this `$2y$10$6D7S2gNkcDciJ7g5z/8sie79iV3FCGhGUCFCPHU3cNNdeUVUbLfQC`

Thanks in advance for any help. :D

Comment: Do you understand how to access an object's property and an array's value?

Comment: If you want it to work with `$this->_result[0]['password']` you should use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: you want to convert object to array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of array can be accessed using key in square brackets eg `$arr[$key].` Property of an object is accessed by using a `->` operator eg `$this->name`

If you just need to print, this is enough:

`print_r($this->_result[0]->password`);

Comment: I edited your answer because indentation wasn't done in `print_r($this->_result[0]->password);` but then I discovered that you have backtick between `password` and `)` - so I did a rollback to your original answer.

Comment: @Pengun You may accept the answer if you feel its helpful to you. :p